# Using a java object saved on memory

Tags: java, file, object, mahout

I have this app (using maven mahout and a dataset, the same from the example https://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/userbased-5-minutes.html). My problem is that I want to divide the task into two sub-tasks. The first task would be calculating the Pearson's Correlation Matrix, and the second task is getting the recommendations (So I would have two .jar files, this is for scalability). My problem is, I don't know how to do that (I read about serializable objects but it did not work). How can I address this problem?

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // Modelo
        DataModel model = null;

        // Inicializar similaridad
        UserSimilarity similarity = null;

        // Leer .cv  userID, itemID, value
        try {
            model = new FileDataModel(new File("data/dataset.csv"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Encontrar matriz de similaridad
        try {
            similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(model);
        } catch (TasteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new ThresholdUserNeighborhood(0.1, similarity, model);
        UserBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);
        java.util.List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = null;
        try {
            recommendations = recommender.recommend(2, 3);
        } catch (TasteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Mostrar Recomendaciones
        for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
            if (recommendation != recommendations.get(recommendations.size() - 1))
                System.out.print(recommendation.getItemID() + " ");
        }
        System.out.print(recommendations.get(recommendations.size() - 1).getItemID());
    }

}
```

Basically I want to store the similarity object into a file, so I can reuse it in another executable

Comment: Which classes do you want to serialize instances of?  What would deserialize them?  Where are the definitions of those classes and their dependencies?

Comment: I want to store the similarity object into a file, so I can reuse it in another executable.

Comment: And what is the similarity object?  All that I know about it is that its name is `UserSimilarity`.  That's not much to go on.

Comment: That are classes from the library I am using. Should I take a peek of what is its internal structure? I don't have access to the source code

Comment: Does it implement `Serializable` or `Externalizable`?

Comment: Nop, it seems that it does not implement anything. Is there a way to have two .jar  files, such that in one I calculate the the  similarity object and I use that in the other one? that is my question. I don't know whether I can implement it serializable without touching the source code of the functions I am already using.

Comment: Serialization lets you copy an object from one JVM to another.  Java RMI allows you to call methods via network messages sent between two JVMs.  Only the arguments and return values need to be serializable for RMI to work.